# Why does this assignment operation results in ambiguous function call?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, function-call, ambiguous-call

Consider following program it compiles and runs fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
struct BB
{
 // generic cast
 template<typename T>
 operator T() const
 {   
   std::cout<<"Generic cast\n";
   return 0;
 }
 // string cast
 operator string() const
 { 
   std::cout<<"string cast\n";
   return string("hello");
 }
};
int main()
{
  BB b;
  string s = b; // copy constructor
}
```

But If I slightly change the `main()` function's code in like following:

```
int main()
{
  BB b;
  string s;
  s = b;
}
```

Compiler give following error message ([See live demo here](http://ideone.com/aOaqpD))

```
[Error] ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'BB')
```

Why this call is ambiguous? What is the reason behind that? It looks like there are so many overloaded `operator=` like one for `char`, one for `char*`, one for `const char*` etc. That's the above program puts compiler into ambiguity.

Comment: In the firstcase this is not assignment operator called, but a copy ctor. However i think that in the second case there is an ambivuity between the template cast operator and the string cast.

Comment: @MaMazav: yes you are right. But my question is about 2nd case where = operator comes into picture.

Comment: On the livedemo page, the error message also lists all the candidates that the compiler considered for resolving the assignment in the second case

Comment: @HellmarBecker, where is this magical "livedemo" page?

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz: read the question to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is your template conversion operator.

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const
{
    std::cout << "Generic cast\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Allows `BB` to be converted to anything.  Because of that all of the overloads of `std::string::operator=` that take a different type can be considered.  Since they are all valid there is no way to resolve the ambiguity and you get the error.

If you removed the template conversion then it will compile.  The template conversion could also be marked as `explicit` and then you can use a `static_cast` to the type you want.

Comment: If you make the templated conversion `explicit` it compiles as well. The `explicit` has the draw back that you would need a `static_cast` for it, but being explicit is probably a good idea with the conversion operators anyway.

Comment: @Niall Thanks for that.  added it into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You call `operator =`, but it would be the same if it were a regular function:

```
void f(int x);
void f(const string &y);

int main() {
    BB b;
    f(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Since `BB` can be cast in either `int` or `string`, the compiler has no idea which `f` function to call.

The only reason why your first example works is because the copy constructor is called there, and it only takes `const string&` as an argument, so there's no multiple choices.